# Discord.js Command Cooldown + Time Remaining

Tags: node.js, json, command, bots, discord.js

Okay so I am looking to make it so that the cooldown shows how much longer the user needs to wait until they can work again. The cool down works butI want it to show the time remainign rather than it saying you need to wait 15 mnutes before typing this command. Is it Possible?

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const { prefix } = require("../../botconfig.json");
const db = require('quick.db')
let bal = require("../../database/balance.json");
let works = require('../../database/works.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const talkedRecently = new Set();

//Set cooldown


module.exports = {
    name: "work",
    aliases: [],
    category: "economy",
    description: "Gets you money",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
       if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
 message.channel.send("You have to wait TIME minutes before you can work again")

    } else {
if(!bal[message.author.id]){
    bal[message.author.id] = {
      balance: 0
    };
  } 
  if(!works[message.author.id]) {
    works[message.author.id] = {
     work: 0
    };
  } 

  const Jwork = require('../../work.json');
  const JworkR = Jwork[Math.floor(Math.random() * Jwork.length)];
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 3;
  let curBal = bal[message.author.id].balance 
  bal[message.author.id].balance = curBal + random;
  let curWork = works[message.author.id].work
  works[message.author.id].work = curWork + 1;
  fs.writeFile('././database/works.json', JSON.stringify(works, null, 2), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    })
  fs.writeFile('././database/balance.json', JSON.stringify(bal, null, 2), (err) => {
    let embed = new RichEmbed() 
    .setColor("RANDOM") 
    .setDescription(`
    **\ | ${message.author.username}**, ${JworkR}  **${random}**
    `) 
    message.channel.send(embed)
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });

        // Adds the user to the set so that they can't talk for a minute
        talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Removes the user from the set after a minute
          talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
        }, 900000);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Rather than using JSON files to store your data, consider a database. You'll notice a worthwhile improvement in speed and ease of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your current system won't be any help. You'll have to store more than just the user if you want to use the timings of their cooldown.

Let's use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for our variable so we can have key-value pairs. This will make it easier to keep track of the information we need

```js
// Replace talkedRecently's declaration with this...
const cooldowns = new Map();
```

To put a user on cooldown, use [`Map.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) to add the user and the time at which their cooldown should expire to `cooldowns`. Then, use [`Map.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete) when the cooldown should run out to allow the user access to the command again.

```js
// Replace the  talkedRecently.add(...)  section with this...
cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 900000);
setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 900000);
```

In order to determine the amount of time remaining on the cooldown, we have to subtract the current time from that at which it expires. However, this will give us milliseconds, rendering the value unreadable to us. A simple, easy way to convert duration into words is by using [`humanize-duration`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration) *([`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) is also an option)*. Finally, we can send the desired message, letting the user know how much time they have left on their cooldown.

```js
// Put this where you require your other dependencies...
const humanizeDuration = require('humanize-duration');

// Replace the  if (talkedRecently.has(...))  part with this...
const cooldown = cooldowns.get(message.author.id);
if (cooldown) {
  const remaining = humanizeDuration(cooldown - Date.now());

  return message.channel.send(`You have to wait ${remaining} before you can work again`)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks it worked but The seconds result in  decimal is there any way where I can make it so that will will just say 14 minutes in 59 Seconds rather than 14 Minutes and 59.254 seconds?

Comment: You can utilize the second parameter of the `humanizeDuration` function to define certain behavior. For example,`{ units: ['m'], round: true }` would give you your desired output. See the package page for more options and detailed usage.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel I addressed all parts of your question, you can use the checkmark to the left of the answer to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).