# Cooldown for Commands not Functioning Discord.js

Tags: javascript, timeout, discord, discord.js

I tried to add cooldown to the command but it doesn't work, There are no errors in console but I can repeatedly use the command. I have tried using `.Map` and `.Set` but neither are working for me. I have refered to these posts.

[Discord.js - Cooldown for a command for each user not all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432102/discord-js-cooldown-for-a-command-for-each-user-not-all-users)

[Discord.js Command Cooldown + Time Remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177125/discord-js-command-cooldown-time-remaining)

Comment: Consider reading this: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns

Comment: My command handler doesn't work with that

Comment: Yeah the point is, you should modify your command handler to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a command handler or save a timestamp to quick.db under a user database. Then when you check if the appropriate time has passed.

**Example:**

```
db.add(`user_${user.id}.time`, Date.now() + <cooldown in ms> ) // For setting a new time
db.get(`user_${user.id}.time`) > Date.now) { do something }// Check if it passed
```